# error: comparison between a pointer and an integer

Tags: c

I am trying to write a simple shell that can handle redirection. However, I get "error: comparison between a pointer and an integer". I understand the why I am getting the error, but I am unsure on how to fix it. 
args is declared as:

```
static char* args[512];
```

This is the code where I am getting the error:

```
if(args == '<'){
     int fd0 = open("input.txt", READ, 0);
     dup2(fd0, STDIN_FILENO);
     close(fd0);
}
if(args == '>'){
     int fd1 = creat("output.txt", 0644);
     dup2(fd1, STDOUT_FILENO);
     close(fd1);
}
```

The error is in the line if(args == '<') and if(args == '>')

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code.  Can you edit your question to indicate which line is generating the error?

Comment: Please update your question to show us how `args` is declared. Also, I'm going to remove the "shell" tag; although your code appears to be part of the implementation of a shell-like program, that's not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that args is a pointer char (char *).
If this is it, you are comparing pointer with single character.
You can do it like this:

```
if(args[0] == '>')
//then do something
```

Comment: A `char*` is a pointer to `char`, not a pointer to an array of chars; that would be a `char (*)[]` or `char (*)[N]`.

Answer (score 1):

With the definition:

```
static char* args[512];
```

the expression `args` will generate a `char **`, which is why it's complaining about comparison with the `'<'`, an `int`.

The correct approach in your case, assuming you want to check the entire string, would be:

```
if (strcmp (args[someIndex], "<") == 0) ...
```

where `someIndex` specifies which array element you want to check.

There's also the possibility that you want to just check the first character of the string (as part of a redirection type of operation, eg: `<infile.txt`) which would be:

```
if (args[someIndex][0] == '<') ...
```

but I consider that unlikely given you don't actually *use* the rest of the argument for opening the file (you use the fixed value `input.txt` instead).

Comment: +1, even without knowing the actual type of `args`. Now the OP added it, you can specify some more.